# Cutting row content by screen perimeter

Tags: flutter

I need to place 2 widgets at Row, and second of them - be "out" of screen's perimeter at be cut by it. Something like at this scheme:
[image]

I tried to override Row's `clipBehavior` property, but that doesn't work.

```
class ClippedRow extends Row {
  ClippedRow({
    super.key,
    super.mainAxisAlignment,
    super.mainAxisSize,
    super.crossAxisAlignment,
    super.textDirection,
    super.verticalDirection,
    super.textBaseline, // NO DEFAULT: we don't know what the text's baseline should be
    super.children,
  });

  @override
  Clip get clipBehavior => Clip.hardEdge;
}

class CardWidget {
  const CardWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget buildWidget(BuildContext context) => ClippedRow(
    children: [
      Widget1(),
      Widget2(), //this one is big and should be "out" of screen
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you want that widget to slide in? or do you don't want to interact with that part of the widget?

Comment: use any widget that allow your row to scroll horizontally or stack

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the row with a **SingleChildScrollView**.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
 child : Row(children: [
  SizedBox(
   width:  //set width here,
   child: Widget1(),
  ), 
  SizedBox(
   width: //define your width
   child: Widget2(),
  ), 
  ]),
)
```

By doing this, you can swipe left to see the more of Widget2().

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to find the width of your screen, you can use this width to your widget.

Comment: thx for answer, but seems like I didn't give a clear context, sorry.  I don't need a scroll, widget 2 had to be fixed and be "cutted" at the same time. Context: I use widget 2 at two different  screens, at the first one it is fully displaced and looked like  whole thing, at the second one - and it is which my question is about - it is placed with widget 1 and shifted by it for the border of device screen.

Comment: You can then, get dynamic width of your screen from MediaQuery and give a width of that width*0.3 to the Widget1() and give the rest ( width*0.7) to the Widget2(). Now if you change your screen size, your widget width should also be changed because of MediaQuery width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code if you want a static non-sliding out of the screen implementation with a `Row`:

```
Stack(children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 50,
          left: 150,
          child: Row(children: [
            Container(height: 50,width: 50,color: Colors.red,),
            Container(height:50, width:200,color: Colors.blue,)
          ],),
        )
      ],),
```

And this code if you want it to be dynamic(replicatable on every device):

```
Stack(children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 50,
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
          child: Row(children: [
            Container(height: 50,width: 50,color: Colors.red,),
            Container(height:50, width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,color: Colors.blue,)
          ],),
        )
      ],),
```

Comment: Thx for answer! For some reason, it is not working - screen is fully clear. If i remove stack widget from you example, it almost works for me, but at the right border of screen it is not just cutted, but "overflowed by "N" pixels".

Comment: Is there an error reported in your logcat or run tab? tell me and I'll fix it

Comment: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
I/flutter ( 2107): The ParentDataWidget Positioned(left: 150.0, top: 50.0) wants to apply ParentData of type StackParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
I/flutter ( 2107): Usually, this means that the Positioned widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Positioned widgets are placed directly inside Stack widgets.
I/flutter ( 2107): The offending Positioned is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.

Comment: I/flutter ( 2107): The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
I/flutter ( 2107):   Row ← Positioned ← WillPopScope ← BackPressHandlerWidget ← CardWithReorder ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← _SelectionKeepAlive ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← ⋯

Comment: Have you used my code directly or under some other widgets can you show me your code?

Comment: thx very much for your efforts, but seems like issue resolved for me by using Transform.translate widget

Comment: Well that's good then :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of getting there, as you can see from the other other answers, but I would use a ListView:

```
SizedBox(
  // here you put the sizes you want
  // you can also use MediaQuery.of(context).size.width to cover the entire screen
  child: ListView(
    // by default it's vertical
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
      Widget1(),
      Widget2(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Oh no, may be I didn't give a clear description, sorry. I don't need a scroll, widget 2 had to be fixed and be "cutted" at the same time. Context: I use widget 2 at two different  screens, at the first one it is fully displaced and looked like  whole thing, at the second one - and it is which my question is about - it is placed with widget 1 and shifted by it for the border of device screen.

Answer (score 0):

thx for all your answers, but what I wanted seems to be achieved by using Transform.translate widget:

```
Widget buildWidget(BuildContext context) =>
      Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(100, 0),
          child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
            Widget1(),
            Widget2(),
          ]));
```

Width parameter must be defined for widget1 and widget2.